# How to make child divs visible in tympanus.net's CSS Radio Checked Tab Method

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have made css tabs using the following method:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentTabs/index.html

I would like to use divs inside the tab's contents (For example if I put a div inside .tabContent1) however their visibility seems to be 0 and their position is absolute.  How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
            <div class="content">               
                <div class="productTabs">
<!-- Tabs Label / Buttons -->
                    <input id="productTab1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="productTabRadio1" checked="checked" />
                    <label for="productTab1" class="productTabLabel1"></label>

                    <input id="productTab2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="productTabRadio2" />
                    <label for="productTab2" class="productTabLabel2"></label>

                    <input id="productTab3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="productTabRadio3" />
                    <label for="productTab3" class="productTabLabel3"></label>

                    <input id="productTab4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="productTabRadio4" />
                    <label for="productTab4" class="productTabLabel4"></label>

                    <input id="productTab5" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="productTabRadio5" />
                    <label for="productTab5" class="productTabLabel5"></label>

                    <input id="productTab6" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="productTabRadio6" />
                    <label for="productTab6" class="productTabLabel6"></label>

                    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- Tabs Content -->
                    <div class="tabContent">
                        <div class="tabContent1">
                            <h2>Our Products and Apps</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tabContent2">
                            <h2>Sage Products</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tabContent3">
                            <h2>Microsoft Products</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tabContent4">
                            <h2>3rd Party Sage Addons</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tabContent5">
                            <h2>Support Packages</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tabContent6">
                            <h2>Cloud Products</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .clear {
    clear: both;
}
.tabs {
    width: 750px;
}
.productTabs input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.productTabs label {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 132px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    color: black;
}
.productTabLabel1 {
    z-index: 6;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab1.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel1:hover {
    z-index: 6;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab1selected.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel2 {
    z-index: 5;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab2.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel2:hover {
    z-index: 5;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab2selected.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel3 {
    z-index: 4;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab3.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel3:hover {
    z-index: 4;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab3selected.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel4 {
    z-index: 3;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab4.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel4:hover{
    z-index: 3;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab4selected.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel5 {
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab5.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel5:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab5selected.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel6 {
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab6.jpg');
}
.productTabLabel6:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url('http://wbrodie.com/jsfiddle/img/tab6selected.jpg');
}
 .clear {
    clear: both;
}
.tabContent {
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    min-height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.tabContent div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;   //makes all tabs content appear in same place

    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;  //Makes content invisivble when not selected

    -webkit-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
}
.productTabs input.productTabRadio1:checked ~ .tabContent .tabContent1,
.productTabs input.productTabRadio2:checked ~ .tabContent .tabContent2,
.productTabs input.productTabRadio3:checked ~ .tabContent .tabContent3,
.productTabs input.productTabRadio4:checked ~ .tabContent .tabContent4,
.productTabs input.productTabRadio5:checked ~ .tabContent .tabContent5,
.productTabs input.productTabRadio6:checked ~ .tabContent .tabContent6{
    z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: One last question, how can I make .tabContent's height expand so 'ts children dont overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

`.tabContent  div {`

To:

`.tabContent > div {`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GtLga/)

At present you are setting all `div` elements within `.tabContent` to `position:absolute` etc, you only want to do this to immediate children (the `>` selector) so as to not affect `div` elements used in the tab content.

Comment: THANKS!!! I have really been pulling my hair out but couldn't see the issue. Much appreciated!